# Proxy settings Python selenium Chrome equivalent

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Currently this is how I am setting proxies for firefox Python Selenium

```
prox = Proxy()
prox.proxyAutoconfigUrl = "http://wpad/wpad.dat"
ff_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
ff_options.set_preference("network.proxy.no_proxies_on", "DOMAIN")
    
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = "FirefoxDriverPATH", proxy= 
prox, options=ff_options)
```

What is the Chrome equivalent, I have tried the below but I get an error

```
c_options= Options()
prox = Proxy()
prox.proxyAutoconfigUrl = "http://wpad/wpad.dat"
prefs = {"network.proxy.no_proxies_on": "DOMAIN"}
c_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
prox.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "ChromeDriverPATH",desired_capabilities=capabilities, options=c_options)
```

Error:

> Exception InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: cannot
> parse capability: proxy
>
> from invalid argument: unrecognized proxy type: unspecified
>
> Stacktrace:
>
> Backtrace:
>
> ```
>     Ordinal0 [0x07F3+6643]
>
>     Ordinal0 [0x44631+19488973]
>
>     Ordinal0 [FC748+2347448]
>
>     Ordinal0 [0123x00E0FD3456954]
>
>     Ordinal0 [0664x00E15555BD4012]
>
>     Ordinal0 [0x00EE66+978]
>
>     Ordinal0 [055x00E4116]
>
>     Ordinal0 [0x00477289]
>
>     Ordinal0 [0x00E407v197]
>
>     Ordinal0 [0x00E48B]
> ```

Comment: is this solve your issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/65170954/11863448

Comment: @Akzy No, it does not have the part for AutoConfigURL